# Accessing JButton that was clicked from ActionPerformed?

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, actionlistener

I have this assignment from college, and I have to have 5 buttons in the interface, and when button is clicked I have to perform action on that button. But when I use "this" in actionPerformed(), it doesn't refer to the "button that was clicked", and I can't workout what it actually refers to.

So:

1. What does "this" refers to in ActionPerformed() action handler?
2. Any nice way to do something with a button "that was clicked", without using a bunch of if statements, by using "e.getActionCommand()"?

Comment: (JButton)AdtionEvent#getSource

Comment: One way to avoid the "switchboard" handler method -- give each JButton it's own ActionListener, perhaps an anonymous inner listener if the code for it is short.

Comment: The "this" in `actionPerformed()` refers to the action listener itself.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [EventObject#getSource()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/EventObject.html#getSource%28%29), which is inherited by ActionEvent.

```
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) { 
    JButton source = (JButton) e.getSource();
    ...
}
```

Within an ActionListener, `this` refers to the ActionListener object itself, not the source object.